# WPF DataGrid & other DataGrid components

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress

My team and I got a new project to be developed with WPF (with plain WPF and/or 3rd party libs) where the DataGrid component needs to have the below features.

1. Header row’s texts in 45 degree angle (or any other angle the user wants)
2. Summary row(s)
3. Summary column(s)
4. Different background color for some row(s) / column(s)
5. Pivot support
6. Ability to specify new commands for row/column for right click event (eg. we will need some commands like "create", "delete", "export", "hide", "disable".. etc)
7. Create a new data row/column by right clicking & selecting "create" on the grid
8. Delete a column/row by right clicking & selecting "delete" on the grid/column
9. Re-order columns/rows manually & alphabetically
10. Duplicate (copies the whole row or column with values). (eg. Copying the column "Product name" should result in "Product name(Copy)", "Product name(Copy 2)"... etc)
11. Disable column/row (shown in the application, but it’s not used in reports and/or other functionalities)
12. If a cell has memo, there is red corner (like comment in excel)
13. There should be maximum length for the column header which is displayed for the user. (If the column name is too long, it will be truncated at a certain point & the whole name is possible to see in tooltip by hovering over the header)
14. Multi-selection of cells & copying their contents
15. Highlighting a row after searching for it (eg. in a search form we search for a particular row by some parameters, and if found that row should be highlighted in the grid)
16. To have headers only for a few columns (eg. out of 5 columns, only 2 columns should have headers)

I have tried the DataGrid component of WPF & I managed to achieve the following.

1. Header row’s texts in 45 degree angle (or any other angle the user wants)
2. Different background color for some row(s) / column(s)
3. Summary column(s)

Then I tried the DataGrid component of DevExpress & I managed to achieve the following.

1. Summary row(s)

Now I have a few questions.

1. Are ALL these features achievable from plain WPF.?
2. Should I need the support of different frameworks/3rd party libs (eg. DevExpress).?
3. What are the advantages of using plain WPF components in terms of performance(speed) & memory consumption.?
4. Are there any more 3rd party libs which provide these features.?
5. **Most importantly, for WPF experts such as yourselves, how long would it take to build such a component, if we were to do it using plain WPF from the scratch.?**

Comment: Instead of asking *many questions*, try to achieve something and if fail - make a *single* question here, posting what you done, what you want, why it doesn't works, etc. Don't forget to use search first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to mention that I work for DevExpress, so it would be a bit unfair for me to give you advices on what component set to use. Instead, I will describe what we offer for a scenario like yours and let you compare yourself.

Below you can find my comments on how to implement your requirements in DevExpress GridControl:

1. You can create a small content template for your column headers and rotate text there.
2. GridControl supports two main types of summaries – group summaries calculated for each group separately and total summaries calculated for all visible grid rows. You can align summaries by columns or just allow them to occupy all the available space. Group summaries can either be displayed in group rows or in group footers below the group. End-users can add/modify/remove summaries at runtime via a built-in dialog. Check the [Data Summaries Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6126) article in our documentation to learn more.
3. GridControl provides support for [calculated (unbound) columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6124). To supply data for a calculated column, either use an expression (there is a built-in expression dialog for end-users) or calculate column values in code.
4. The best way to modify a background color for certain columns/rows and implement other formatting is to use our [Excel-style Conditional Formatting feature](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17130). Conditional formatting rules can either be defined in xaml or configured by end-users at runtime.
5. There is a separate [PivotGridControl component](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfPivotGridPivotGridControltopic) for working with OLAP data sources and easy chart integration.
6. There is a set of built-in commands for common grid operations (add, delete, show a print dialog, etc.). Of course, you can also implement custom commands if you like.
7. There is a special [New Item Row](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6258) feature for in-place row creation. If you don’t want to initialize row values directly in the grid, you can
8. You can add a corresponding menu item to a context menu for grid rows and invoke a built-in “delete row” command there. Here is a corresponding example in our database:

[How to delete grid rows via the DeleteFocusedRow grid command](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1791)

9. GridControl supports various sorting modes, built-in and custom, to order rows. You can also reorder rows using a built-in drag-and-drop manager (see [Drag and Drop overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11346) topic). Columns can also be reordered using drag-and-drop operations (this functionality is enabled by default).
10. You can implement this “copy a row” and “copy a column” functionality manually and, for example, add corresponding items to a built-in grid context menu for columns and rows.
11. You can implement this functionality manually and add corresponding menu items as well.
12. There is a special MemoEdit editor shipped with DevExpress. If you don’t want to use this editor, create a cell template with a red corner element and bind it to a cell’s comment.
13. Use the MaxWidth property to restrict the grid column width. The column will behave exactly as you described.
14. Cell multi-selection as well as copying/pasting to Excel or other programs are fully supported.
15. GridControl has a built-in [search form](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11403) that shows up when you press Ctrl+F. When you search in the grid using this form, the grid highlights found text. It is also possible to use a separate search form or just bind the search text to the grid, if necessary.
16. Most likely, this can be implemented, but I cannot give any suggestions for now, since it’s not quite clear to me what should be displayed in the header panel for columns without headers. Should there be just blank space?

Lastly, I’d like to address your question regarding performance. There are two main factors affecting performance in the grid: render performance and the performance of data operations. While it’s pretty hard to compare GridControl data operation performance to the standard WPF DataGrid, since DataGrid don’t support many data operations, you can use one of our special sources to work with data at the server side (i.e., propagate data queries directly to a database or a WCF server). In this case, data operation performance for large data sources will increase dramatically. There is also an option for the grid to work with data in multiple threads so that the UI never freeze.

As for render performance, I can share some numbers with you. We made significant performance optimization in our latest version (14.1) and did some tests against DataGrid. Here is what we found out (all tests are performed with a full-screen grid on a standard full-hd monitor):

```
Tree creation (hot start)
Tree Creation  14.1 optimized mode MS DataGrid
Text сolumns        266                375
Check columns       296                610
DateTime columns    312                 -
ComboBox columns    297                765

Vertical Scrolling:
Vertical Scrolling        DevExpress GridCont  MS DataGrid
(1000 Rows 16 columns)
Text сolumns                          1484        2109
Check columns                         1359        1390
DateTime columns                      2062          -
ComboBox columns                      1391        5532
```

We could not measure horizontal scrolling here, since the standard DataGrid don’t have horizontal scrolling virtualization.

Of course, these numbers illustrate only one particular case and we still think that the best way to compare products is to try them manually in a required scenario. If you need any assistance when evaluating our controls, you are welcome to post any questions in our Support Center (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). We will be more than happy to help you.